# Is there any way to change the "Invalid password, please try again' text?

Tags: 14.04, login, password, sudo

I wanted to change the  "Invalid password, please try again' text to "PERMISSION DENIED... and... YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!"

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is coded into sudo and you can either recompile (I doubt you want to do that) or configure sudo.

I HIGHLY SUGGEST you use `visudo` . `visudo` checks the syntax of your sudoers file and helps reduce the possibility of breakage due to a typo.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

You add or edit the line(s)

```
Defaults        lecture_file = /etc/sudo.message
Defaults        lecture = always
```

you then write a "/etc/sudo.message" file to read "PERMISSION DENIED... and... YOU DIDN'T SAY THE MAGIC WORD!" or whatever you want.

from man sudoers

> lecture
>      This option controls when a short lecture will be printed along with the password prompt. It has the following possible values:
>
> always - Always lecture the user.
>
> never -  Never lecture the user.
>
> once -   Only lecture the user the first time they run sudo.
>
> If no value is specified, a value of once is implied. Negating the option results in a value of never being used. The default value is once.
>
> lecture_file
>
> Path to a file containing an alternate sudo lecture that will be used in place of the standard lecture if the named file exists. By default, sudo uses a built-in lecture.

See http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html for details and additional options.